# expiring a webpage (Like seen on bank sites)

Tags: php, jquery, security, http

I am making a php system (on apache server) and I need to make the site extremely secure,
One of my requirements is to make sure that any visit to a page other from a direct link from the website (even a "back" button) will reset the session and demand another login (redirection to the login screen).

The entire system is up and running, I use php and jquery in my code.

I had an idea about making a function that is being called every 1 minute (or so) and "remake" a token for the next 1 minute(or just a little bit longer, if the function doesn't get approval from the server then the browser will redirect to the login screen.

What do you think about that solution? would it be too "heavy" on the internet connection? (we usually have edge/2g internet connection over ipad).

if I do make this solution, how can I make sure that at the moment when user presses the back button or enters the site he wont be shown any data?

thanks in advance.

Comment: For starters, use a low session timeout and listen for the `onbeforeunload` event to do stuff when the users presses the back button/closes the browser.

Comment: Yes, a low session timeout and then a JS timer kicked off that pops up after the same timeout delay.

Comment: @Dagon, The banks I use dont let you press the "back" button, the page will say "page expired".

Comment: just tested all 3 i use and none do that. don't know why my original comment was deleted- was not none by me.

Answer (score 0):

use sessions to validate some one presence .

then you can destroy its session and expire its session!

like:

```
session_destroy();
```

Comment: The whole point of session_destroy is to eliminate all the sessions, if I use it I lose the user data (as for who is logged in).

Comment: set a session variable with a timestamp, check that for your actions. expire him if that is not active, or update it on activity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution was making a function that is being called every 1 minute (or so) and "remake" a token for the next 1 minute(or just a little bit longer, if the function doesn't get approval from the server then the browser will redirect to the login screen.